# JS: Moving an anchor with insertAdjacentHTML only appends the href, not the element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move an anchor tag from one element to another.  When I do this, the only thing appended is the anchors href, not the element itself.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

I need a solution in Javascript only as jQuery isn't being used

Thanks for any help!

**Fidde:** https://jsfiddle.net/p7g7mkxs/

**What I've tried:**

```
<p class="hello">hello</p>
<p class="hello">hello<a href="#link">LINK</a></p>

var hello = document.querySelectorAll('.hello');
hello[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', hello[1].querySelectorAll('a')[0]);
```

I've also tried using different variations of selecting my elements, like `getElementsByTagName` or appending it differently with `innerHTML` - Everything I've tried has given me the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `insertAdjacentHTML` with **HTML** (a string), not with an actual element. If you pass it an element, the element is converted to string (like `String(theElement)`). In the case of an `HTMLAnchorElement`, that means you just get the `href`. Proof:

```js
console.log(
  String(document.querySelector("a"))
);
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Hey</a>
```

To append an element to the end of another element's child list, use [`appendChild`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107):

```
var hello = document.querySelectorAll('.hello');
hello[0].appendChild(hello[1].querySelector('a'));
```

(To insert it elsewhere, use [`insertBefore`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727). Actually, you can use `insertBefore` in all cases if you like, just use `null` as the reference element when adding to the end.)

---

Also note that when you only want the first match, rather than `querySelectorAll(/*...*/)[0]`, use `querySelector(/*...*/)`, which returns the first match or `null`.

Comment: I was only using [0] to keep it as true to my original code as possible, I'm looping through the elements so 0's are actually i's.  BUT... That makes a lot more sense now, thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @t-j-crowder said, you can also use `outerHTML` to accomplish the task:

```
var hello = document.querySelectorAll('.hello');

hello[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', hello[1].querySelectorAll('a')[0].outerHTML);
```